# Update statement according to condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, phppgadmin

How to update the discount_price in DB 
I need to add value to existing value according to my condition
Example: any product has the price from 10 to 30 
I have to add 1.5 to it.

product with 15 should be 16.5 for example

I have written this query

```
UPDATE products
    SET discount_price = discount_price + 1.5 
    WHERE discount_price >= 10 AND discount_price <= 30;
```

But I found this error >>

SQL error:

> ```
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SET"
> LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM (UPDATE products SET discount_...
>                                                        ^
> In statement:
> SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM (UPDATE products SET discount_price = discount_price + 1.5 
> WHERE discount_price >= 10 AND discount_price <=30) AS sub
> ```

[image]

Comment: The query that you have written and the one in the error message are different.

Comment: Nope. When I clicked execute the query, I got this error  in the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you are using Postgres and want to count the number of rows affected by an update.  If so, you can use an updatable CTE:

```
WITH p as (
      UPDATE products
          SET discount_price = discount_price + 1.5 
          WHERE discount_price >= 10 AND discount_price <= 30
          RETURNING *
     )
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM p;
```

There is no equivalent syntax in MySQL.

Comment: I got this 

ERROR:  WITH clause containing a data-modifying statement must be at the top level
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM (WITH p as (
                                            ^
In statement:

SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM (WITH p as (
      UPDATE products
          SET discount_price = discount_price + 1.5 
          WHERE discount_price >= 10 AND discount_price <= 30
          RETURNING *
     )
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM p) AS sub

Comment: @MohammadKanaan . . . You have other code that you are not showing.  I don't know where the `select count(*)` is coming from, but it is somewhere.

Comment: Can you Access my laptop via team viewer to see the problem please ?